# Type Error - Referencing Javascript Classes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typeerror

Firstly a little elaboration of the project I'm working on. I have started building a 'map maker' for a 2d game I am working on. The project is just for fun and has proven so far to be a great way to learn new things.

I recently showed my working map maker code to a friend who suggested it would be much more re-usable if I restructured the project to be more OOR, which I am now attempting.

The problem I have is when I add a 'Guild' instance to my map, the first one works fine, but the second causes a type error that is giving me a headache!

I will post all of the relevant code from the different files below, but the overall structure is as follows:

Map.js = Map class file, container for setting the map overall size and iterating over (and placing) map objects.

MapObject.js = Class file for simple map objects such as walls, contains the position and icon properties.

Guild.js = Class file, extends MapObject.js, this is where my problem seems to be, adds an additional 'MapIcon' and will have other features such as levels and names etc.

map-maker.js = Main file for generating the map-maker page, utilises the above class files to create the map.

Below is the code used to create an instance of 'Guild' on my map:

map-maker.js (creating the map / map object / guild instances)

```
// Initialise a new instance of map class from Map.js using the user 
provided values for #mapX and #mapY.
var currentMap = new Map(XY,40);

// Get the user box volume * map boxsize from Map.js
currentMap.calcDimensions();

 // Create a Map Object and push it to the currentMap with its position.
function createMapObject(x,y,floor){
currentMap.objects.push(new MapObject(x,y,floor));
```

}

```
 // Create a Guild Object (extension of Map Object) and push it to the currentMap with its position.
function createGuildObject(x,y,floor){
currentMap.objects.push(new Guild(x,y,floor));
```

}

```
....

 case 13: // Enter Key (Submit)
        unhighlightTools();
        currentMap.drawMap();
        if(currentFloor != null){
            currentFloor.hasFloor = true;
            if(currentFloor.tileName == "Guild"){
                createGuildObject(currentFloor.position.x,currentFloor.position.y,currentFloor);
            }else {
            createMapObject(currentFloor.position.x,currentFloor.position.y,currentFloor);
            }
        console.log("Map object created at - X:"+currentFloor.position.x+" Y:"+currentFloor.position.y);
        }
        currentFloor = [];
        highlightTools();
        break;
}
```

Guild.js (constructor and assigning map icon)

```
class Guild extends MapObject {
constructor(x,y,floor) {
    super(x,y,floor);
    this.levels = [];
}

mapIcon() {
    this.mapIcon = new Image();
    this.mapIcon.src = "../images/mapSprites/obj-1.png"
    return this.mapIcon;
}
}
```

MapObject.js (position setup and constructor)

```
class MapObject {
constructor(x,y,floor) {
    this.position = {x, y};
    this.icon = this.wallFloorIcons(floor);
}

wallFloorIcons(floor) {
this.img = new Image();
this.name = "";
this.name += (floor.wallNorth) ? 'n' : ''; 
this.name += (floor.wallEast) ? 'e' : '';
this.name += (floor.wallSouth) ? 's' : '';
this.name += (floor.wallWest) ? 'w' : '';

this.name = 'wall-'+this.name+'.png';

if(this.name == 'wall-.png'){
    this.img.src = "../images/mapSprites/floor.png";
}else {
    this.img.src = "../images/mapSprites/"+this.name;
}
return this.img;
}

getIcon() {
    return this.img;
}
}
```

Map.js (processing the objects at a given location and drawing the canvas)

```
class Map {

// Map Width / Height and number of boxes. Used to generate map and zoom level.
constructor(wh, boxSize) {
    this.size = wh;
    this.width = wh[0];
    this.height = wh[1];
    this.boxSize = boxSize;
    this.objects = [];
    this.boxes = wh[0];
}

// Calculates the width and height * boxSize for rendering the canvas.
calcDimensions(){
    this.realX = Math.floor(this.width * this.boxSize);
    this.realY = Math.floor(this.height * this.boxSize);
    this.realX = parseInt(this.realX,10); 
    this.realY = parseInt(this.realY,10);
    this.realXY = [
        this.realX,
        this.realY
    ];
    return this.realXY;
}

// Draws the canvas, grid and adds the objects that belong to the map.
drawMap(){
    var self = this;

    self.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    self.c = self.canvas.getContext("2d");

    self.background = new Image(); 
    self.background.src = "../images/mapSprites/oldPaperTexture.jpg"; 

    // Make sure the image is loaded first otherwise nothing will draw.
    self.background.onload = function(){
        self.c.drawImage(self.background,0,0);
        self.fillMap(); 
    }
}

fillMap(){
    var self = this;

    self.c.lineWidth = 1;
    self.c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    self.c.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)";

    for (var row = 0; row < self.boxes; row++) {
        for (var column = 0; column < self.boxes; column++) {
            var x = column * self.boxSize;
            var y = row * self.boxSize;

            self.c.beginPath();
            self.c.rect(x, y, self.boxSize, self.boxSize);
            self.c.stroke();
            self.c.closePath();

            for (var i=0; i<self.objects.length; i++) {
                var floor = self.objects[i];
                if (floor.position.x == column && floor.position.y == row) {  
                    if (self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y}) != null) {
                        var mapObjects = self.objectsAtPosition({x:floor.position.x, y:floor.position.y})
                        for (var mapObject of mapObjects) {
                            this.c.drawImage(mapObject.getIcon(), x, y, self.boxSize, self.boxSize);
                            console.log(mapObject);
                            if(mapObject instanceof Guild){
                                console.log(mapObject);
                                this.c.drawImage(mapObject.mapIcon(), x, y, self.boxSize, self.boxSize);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }     
            }
        }
    }
}

deleteObject(pos){
    this.objectsAtPosition(pos);
    for( var i = 0; i < this.objects.length; i++){
        if(this.objects[i] == this.objs){
            delete this.objects[i];
            this.objects.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
}

objectsAtPosition(position) {
    var objs = [];
    for (var o of this.objects) {
        if (o.position.x == position.x && o.position.y == position.y) {
            objs.push(o);
        }
    }
    return objs;
}
}
```

When I run the code, this is my error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: mapObject.mapIcon is not a function
at Map.fillMap (Map.js:70)
at Image.self.background.onload (Map.js:39)
```

The error comes after I add 1 guild then try to add any other map object. Guild or otherwise.

Sorry if this question is a little vague, I'm still learning (as you can see :p).

Thanks for your time!
Earl Lemongrab

Comment: You know that theres a native Map class?

Comment: I did know that... And I have just realised how bad it is that I have named my class the same thing. I will definitely change that, but still looking for an answer to the current issue, as it's got me very confused.

Comment: I'd start with looking into what `mapObjects` contains. Then figure out what writes to `mapObjects`

Comment: I'm a little confused. When are any elements added to `this.objects` in Map.js?

Comment: Apologies! I missed that out. In map-maker.js there are the following functions:

      `// Create a Map Object and push it to the currentMap with its position.
      function createMapObject(x,y,floor){
          currentMap.objects.push(new MapObject(x,y,floor));
      }`

     `// Create a Guild Object (extension of Map Object) and push it to the currentMap with its position.
function createGuildObject(x,y,floor){
    currentMap.objects.push(new Guild(x,y,floor));
}`

I'll add this to the main post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution from a friend in the end.

The issue was that I was reassigning `this.mapIcon = new Image()` so it exploded when it was called a second time.

Feel pretty silly for not spotting it.

Thanks for the help everyone.